# real analysis part 2

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need help I'm so clueless on how to do this one

1. Suppose $\sum n a_n$ is absolutely convergent and
   define $f(x)  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty   a_n   \cos{n x}$
   define $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty   a_n    \sin{n x}$. 
   Are these functions differentiable for all $x$? Prove or disprove, if they are differentiable find the derivatives.
2. Let $S_n$ be a non decreasing sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and suppose $S_n \to S$ , which is also continuous on $[a,b]$ prove $S_n \to  S$ uniformly.

Comment: Hint: What's the most that the derivative of $\sin nx$ or $\cos nx$ can attain? What theorems do you have at your disposal? That will help us help you.

Comment: proof of second question follows from Dini Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Let
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cos(kx).
$$
It is clear that each $f_n$ is differentiable and 
$$
f_n'(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^nka_k\sin(kx),\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_k$ is absolutely convergent, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k|a_k|=0.
$$
Therefore there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k|a_k| \le \varepsilon \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
For $n,p \in \mathbb{N}$ let $z=z(n,p) \in [0,2\pi]$ such that
$$
|f_{n+p}'(z)-f_n'(z)|=\max_{0\le x \le 2\pi}|f_{n+p}'(x)-f_n'(x)|.
$$
For every $n,p\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge N$ we have
$$
|f_{n+p}'(z)-f_n'(z)|\le \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}k|a_k| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k|a_k| \le \varepsilon,
$$ 
i.e.
$$
\|f_{n+p}'-f_n'\|_{C([0,2\pi])} \le \varepsilon \quad \forall n \ge N.
$$
The latter shows that $\{f_n'\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C([0,2\pi])$. Thus, we have
$$
\lim_nf_n'=\tilde{f} \in C([0,2\pi]),
$$
and
$$
\tilde{f}(x)=\lim_nf_n'(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_k\cos(kx) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Given $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have 
$$
f_n(x)-f_n(a)=\int_a^xf_n'(s)\,ds\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Since the converges $f_n' \to \tilde{f}$ is uniform on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that
$$
f(x)-f(a)=\lim_n(f_n(x)-f_n(a))=\lim_n\int_a^xf_n'(s)\,ds=\int_a^x\lim_nf_n'(s)\,ds=\int_a^x\tilde{f}(s)\,ds,
$$
hence $f'=\tilde{f}$. This shows that $f$ is differentiable. Similarly one shows that $g$ is differentiable and 
$$
g'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_k\cos(kx) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

**2.** This is Dini's Theorem (see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) )

Comment: +1 for the effort. Most people would have just shown the final answer and given a link to Dini's theorem.